# Spring Security Multiples token-endpoint-url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to use multiples end points urls?

I have created an `/oauth/v2/token` endpoint and I was able to make it work.

But I want to use it and the native endpoint (/oauth/token) both at the same time.
The `oauth:authorization-server` accepts just one token-endpoint-url

```
<oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"  
                     token-endpoint-url="/oauth/v2/token" >
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:password/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="appTokenGranter"/>
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: would be easier to make an redirect in some web server in front of your app